# Is there a way I can achieve Torque control from pulse control?

Tags: control, stepper-motor

I am using the **Contec SMC-8DL** Motion control card to control the Oriental Stepper motors via the **AZD-C driver**. The Contec helper functions only allow for sending pulses to the driver, is there a way of instead of sending pulse I send the torque commands?

Best

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* daRula, but I'm afraid that questions which can only be answered by the pre-sales or technical support team for a specific manufacturer or supplier aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. *[Practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)* are always welcome here though, so if you edit your question to fit our community guidelines we can reopen it for you. Please take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.